# Passing a Map between Main class and and an extended Abstract class in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class, pass-by-reference

I have a Main class where I have a Map declared and passing this as a reference to a class that extends an Abstract class

```
MainClass.java:
public class MainClass{
      private final Map<String, String> folderMap = new HashMap<>();
      
      public static void main() {   
         Tester testObj = new TesterImpl(folderMap);
         testObj.implementation();
         System.out.println(folderMap); //[key1,value1]
      }

}

Tester.java:
public abstract class Tester {

   public abstract void implementation();
}

TesterImpl.java:
public class TesterImpl extends Tester {
      private final Map<String, String> folderMap = new HashMap<>();
      
      public TesterImpl(Map<String, String> folderMap) {
          this.folderMap = folderMap;
      }
      
      public void implementation() {
          folderMap.put("key1","value1");
      }

}
```

The question is when I print the folderMap in MainClass.java, how does it have the values of the folderMap that was added in the TesterImpl class when I'm just passing the reference of folderMap.

Also, is this the best way to achieve sharing of the folderMap variable across the classes.If not any suggestions on a better aproach?

Comment: Read this https://www.baeldung.com/java-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference#2-passing-object-references

Comment: Java is pass by value. So, you are passing the value (the actual HashMap from `MainClass`) to the `TesterImpl` which is then assigned to the `folderMap` field.

Comment: Both fields reference the same map (after assigning the field in the constructor). Abstract class is irrelevant here. `... folderMap = new HashMap<>();` assignment is redundant, because it is immediately overwritten in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... The question is when I print the folderMap in MainClass.java, how does it have the values of the folderMap that was added in the TesterImpl class when I'm just passing the reference of folderMap. ..."*

Possibly, you have the terminology mixed-up.

You're passing an *Object* *data-type* to *TesterImpl*, rather than a *primitive* *data-type*.
In *Java*, the *Object* instance will be resolved, and not the content, or *"value"*, of the *Object*.

On the contrary, if you use a *primitive* *data-type*, the literal value is passed, and not an *address*, or *"instance"*.
Hence, the *MainClass* value would be unaffected.

Languages such as *C*, *C++*, and *Rust*, offer the concept you're referring to, for *primitive* *data-types*.

The topic is typically referred to as, *"[referencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))"*.

> *"... is this the best way to achieve sharing of the folderMap variable across the classes.If not any suggestions on a better aproach?"*

The best approach would depend on the cumulative usage of *folderMap*.

If it's a single operation, I imagine what you have is valid.

Otherwise, make *folderMap* available to *TesterImpl*, through *[inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.

```java
class MainClass{
    Map<String, String> folderMap;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tester testObj = new TesterImpl();
        testObj.implementation();
        System.out.println(folderMap); //[key1,value1]
    }

}

abstract class Tester extends MainClass {

    public abstract void implementation();
}

class TesterImpl extends Tester {
    public void implementation() {
        folderMap.put("key1","value1");
    }

}
```